# How define TextArea in dev Express

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I want to add description custom that's why i need textArea devexpress and this is the code  can someone tell me how change this to be TextArea.

```
 @Html.DevExpress().TextBox(f =>
{
    f.Name = "Description";
    f.Text = "";
    f.Width = 300;
    f.Height = 30;

    f.Properties.NullText = "saisir description Module";
}).GetHtml()
```

and thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the [MVCxMemo](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebMvcMVCxMemoMembersTopicAll) in MVC and [ASPxMemo](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsASPxMemoMembersTopicAll) in ASP.NET.

> Memo is an editor allowing multi-line text to be displayed and edited.

```
@Html.DevExpress().Memo(
    settings => {
        settings.Name = "memo1";

        settings.Text = "The editor's size can be controlled either by its Width and Height properties or, if they are not defined, by using the Columns and Rows properties.";

        settings.Properties.Columns = 40;
        settings.Properties.Rows = 6;
    }).GetHtml()
```

Referenes:
[MVC Extension - @Html.DevExpress().TextBox Multilines](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q403181)
[TextArea](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q333287)
[Implement TextArea](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T204126)